# iFrame error on youTube video insert with video.js player

Tags: html, iframe, video, html5-video, video.js

I use video.js with the vjs.youtube.js plugin to play youTube videos within the video.js player on my site. It all works quite fine and videos can be added to the page dynamically.

But the problem happens whenever I try to add multiple youtube videos.
The problem is that Chrome throws out the following error:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "http://mysite.local". Protocols, domains, and ports
>   must match.

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It works only online, in local it doesn't.

Comment: I don't know, I think YouTube blocks local connection on his server.

Comment: I guess not. They shouldn't even be able to tell.